# Rutas angular y htaccess

Tags: angular, .htaccess

Tengo una web en la cual las rutas son de la siguiente manera:

miweb.com/#/galeria

Necesito que al escribir miweb.com/galeria entienda que debe entrar ahí, pero no logro hacerlo, mi htaccess actual es el siguiente, pero me dice que no está redirigiend adecuadamente:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !folder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Tengo activado el *use hash* en angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hagas el cambio por htaccess en tu proyecto de angular donde tienes las rutas principal utiliza este código

```
export const APP_ROUTES = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
useHash: false,
preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
```

});

Al usar `usehash: false`, anulas el /# de la URL y al utilizar el `preloadingStrategy`, los clientes podrán cargar la URL sin pasar por la home

Comment: Cannot find name 'PreloadAllModules'.ts(2304), me dice lo siguiente, sabes que puede ser? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Le falto mencionar que tienes que importar ese módulo de las rutas, así: `import {  PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: Exacto, debes importar el paquete, te recomiendo que uses Visual Studio Code, te ayuda muchisimo con los paquetes

Comment: importe el preloadallmodules en el app-routing.module.ts pero me tira 404 cuando quiero acceder a alguna ruta